# ggplot2 - drawing a line between two y variables next to each other for each of the three x's (with two color categories)

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this

```
 X  A      y   ysd   yse     y2  ysd2  yse2

40  1   46.1  21.2  2.48   42.8  20.1  2.35
40  2   36.6  20.6  2.28   39.9  22.0  2.43
60  1   61.7  25.3  2.87   61.5  23.9  2.71
60  2   53.7  20.9  2.23   52.4  20.8  2.22
80  1   58.7  33.5  3.68   63.2  30.9  3.40
80  2   62.5  29.7  3.18   70.5  20.7  2.21
```

I am trying to plot y and y2 next to each other, connected with a line, for each X (with +/- SE vertical lines, and color variable A). I've combed through similar questions but couldn't find anything that helped. The closest I got was by nudging the second variable to the right, but it looks sloppy (X axis labels) and I can't figure out how to connect the variables with a line.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=X, color=A)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(y=y, ymin=y-yse, ymax=y+yse)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(y=y2, ymin=y2-yse2, ymax=y2+yse2), position=position_nudge(x=5))
```

Here's the picture I get (labels are a bit off since my variables are named differently in actual dataset):

[image]

I essentially am trying to get something like the picture (but less sloppy) where the two dots of each color in each section (X=40, 60, 80) are connected by a line.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `geom_segment()`?

Comment: Check out the [geom_path](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html) documentation and look into using a `group = X` call in the `aes`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: added 2nd approach.

You could add a line_segment and specify `xend` to be shifted 5:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=X, color=A)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(y=y, ymin=y-yse, ymax=y+yse)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(y=y2, ymin=y2-yse2, ymax=y2+yse2), position=position_nudge(x=5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = X+5, y = y, yend = y2))
```

[image]

---

Or, a different approach by first making the table longer:

```
a %>%
  gather(col, val, -c(X,A)) %>%
  mutate(class = if_else(col %>% str_detect("2"), 2, 1),
         col = col %>% str_remove("2")) %>%
  spread(col, val) %>%
  mutate(adj_X = X + if_else(class == 1, -1, 1) * 2) %>%

ggplot(aes(x=adj_X, color=A)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(y=y, ymin = y - yse, ymax = y + yse)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = interaction(X, A), y = y))
```

[image]